# How to make a while loop in ssh session in shell scripting?

Tags: ssh, shell-script

I want to execute a while loop in a ssh session.

This works fine in local host, but while trying under ssh session, it is not getting value of loop variables and others variables as well.

What could be the reason, how to fix it?

```
for hostname in host1 host2 <<EOF
do
count=$(echo $destinationPath|grep -o "/"|wc -l)
echo "dirCount=$dirCount"
path="/"
i=1;
while [ $i -lt $count ]
do
        echo "i=$i";
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
        dir=$(echo $destinationPath|cut -d'/' -f$i);
        echo "dir=$dir";
        path=$path$dir/
        echo "path=$path";
done
exit
done
EOF
```

Comment: Let me clarify, do you want to loop through a list of hosts then execute a command on each using ssh?

Comment: Are you using the same shell both on your localhost and on the server that you are connecting to?

Comment: Write the script, and `scp` the script to the host and execute it.

Comment: Where are the variables set and what expansions would you want to do locally and what expansions would you want to remotely?